# denoise image segmentation (mode filtering?) - or how to vectorize this operation in numpy?

Tags: numpy, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation, numba

*UPDATE: In my initial post I stupidly applied `stats.mode` patch-wise rather than along the axis of the patches.  Fixing this increased my speed by a factor of 4. however its still slow and my original questions still exist: (1) can i increase the speed? (2) are there different/better/standard approaches to cleaning up noisy categorical data? Back the post:*

I have some image segmentation results that are noisy and I want to clean it up. My idea was to take the mode value for (3,3) patches.  This code works but its too slow.:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image
from scipy import stats

def _mode(a,axis=None):
    m,_=stats.mode(a,axis=axis)
    return m   

def mode_smoothing(data,kernel=(3,3)):
    patches=image.extract_patches_2d(data,kernel)
    nb_patches=patches.shape[0]
    patches=patches.reshape(nb_patches,-1)
    return _mode(patches,1).reshape(int(np.sqrt(nb_patches)),-1)


""" original method (new version is ~ 5 times faster, but still slow)
def _mode(arr):
    m,_=stats.mode(arr,axis=None)
    return m   

def mode_smoothing(data,kernel=(3,3)):
    patches=image.extract_patches_2d(data,kernel)
    nb_patches=patches.shape[0]
    w=int(np.sqrt(nb_patches))
    o=np.array([_mode(patches[p]) for p in range(nb_patches)])
    return o.reshape(w,-1)
"""
```

Questions:

1. Is there a way to do this that is much much faster? eliminate for loop/vectorize in numpy? porting to c directly or using numba etc? I struggled getting something to work along these paths
2. Are there better / more standard methods for accomplishing denoising like this on categorical image data?

Here is a before/after example from the `mode_smoothing` method above

[image: noisy segmentation]
[image: after mode filter]

Comment: You can try to split the image into layers. To process each layer separately. I think using morphology or median filter. Then, merge the processed layers back.

Comment: Thanks AA - If I understand you're suggesting splitting each category into a layer - apply a median filter (giving values 0-1) and then merge back with an argmax or something.  its a really interesting thought.  last night I got a numba version to work (i'll update shortly) so i've now solved question (1) -- making it fast enough.  but your methodolgoy might give better results.  I'll give it a try and maybe post comparisons before closing out this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below I present 2 answers to question my question:

1. by expanding out my initial attempt into a function that numba can handle
2. using the above suggestion by [Alex Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13226440/alex-alex), which i'll call "categorical-smoothing" (is there a standard name for this method?)

I haven't written out a mathematical proof yet but it appears this patch-wise mode smoothing is equivalent to the categorical-smoothing for the correct choice of parameters. Both lead to a big speed-boost but categorical-smoothing solution is cleaner, faster, and doesn't involve numba - so it wins.

---

### NUMBA

```py
@njit
def mode_smoothing(data,kernel=(3,3),step=(1,1),edges=False,high_value=False,center_boost=False):
    """ mode smoothing over patches

    Args:
        data<np.array>: numpy array (ndim=2)
        kernel<tuple[int]>: (height,width) of patch window
        step<tuple[int]>: (y-step,x-step)
        edges<bool>: 
            - if true 
                * include edge patches by taking mode over smaller patch window 
                * the returned image be the same shape as the input data
            - if false
                * only run over patches with the full kernel size
                * the returned image will be reduced in size by the radius of the kernel
        high_value<bool>: 
            when there are multiple possible mode values choose the highest if true, 
            otherwise choose the lowest value
        center_boost<int|bool>: 
            if true, instead of using pure mode-value increase the count on the center pixel
    Return
        <np.array> of patch wise mode values. shape my be different than input. see `edges` above
    """
    h,w=data.shape
    ry=int(kernel[0]//2)
    rx=int(kernel[1]//2)
    sy,sx=step

    _mode_vals=[]

    if edges:
        j0,j1=0,h
        i0,i1=0,w
    else:
        j0,j1=ry,h-ry
        i0,i1=rx,w-rx

    for j in range(j0,j1,sy):
        for i in range(i0,i1,sx):

            ap=data[
                max(j-ry,0):j+ry+1,
                max(i-rx,0):i+rx+1]

            cv=data[j,i]

            values=np.unique(ap)
            count=0
            for v in values:
                newcount=(ap==v).sum()
                if center_boost and (v==cv):
                    newcount+=center_boost
                if high_value:
                    test=newcount>=count
                else:
                    test=newcount>count
                if test:
                    count=newcount
                    mode_value=v     
            _mode_vals.append(mode_value)

    return np.array(_mode_vals).reshape(j1-j0,i1-i0)
```

---

### CATEGORICAL SMOOTHING

```py
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
KERNEL=np.ones((3,3))

def categorical_smoothing(data,nb_categories,kernel=KERNEL):
    data=np.eye(nb_categories)[:,data]
    for i in range(nb_categories):
        data[i]=convolve2d(data[i],kernel,mode='same')
    return data.argmax(axis=0)
```

---

### EQUIVALENCE/SPEED-CHECK

This is probably easy to prove but...

```py
S=512
N=19
data=np.random.randint(0,N,(S,S))
%time o1=mode_smoothing(data,edges=True,center_boost=False)
kernel=np.ones((3,3))
%time o2=categorical_smoothing(data,N,kernel=kernel)
print((o1==o2).all())
print()
data=np.random.randint(0,N,(S,S))
%time o1=mode_smoothing(data,edges=True,center_boost=1)
kernel=np.ones((3,3))
kernel[1,1]=2
%time o2=categorical_smoothing(data,N,kernel=kernel)
print((o1==o2).all())

""" OUTPUT
CPU times: user 826 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 826 ms
Wall time: 825 ms
CPU times: user 416 ms, sys: 7.83 ms, total: 423 ms
Wall time: 423 ms
True

CPU times: user 825 ms, sys: 3.78 ms, total: 829 ms
Wall time: 828 ms
CPU times: user 422 ms, sys: 3.91 ms, total: 426 ms
Wall time: 425 ms
True
"""
```